# Writing hex value into file Python

Tags: python, c, string

What I am really doing is creating a BMP file from JPEG using python and it's got some header data which contains info like size, height or width of the image, so basically I want to read a JPEG file, gets it width and height, calculate the new size of a BMP file and store it in the header.

Let's say the new size of the BMP file is 40000 bytes whose hex value is `0x9c40`, now as there is 4 byte space to save this in the header, we can write it as `0x00009c40`. In BMP header data, LSB is written first and then MSB so I have to write, `0x409c0000` in the file.

My Problems:-

1. I was able to do this in C but I am totally lost how to do so in Python.

   For example, if I have `i=40000`, and by using `str=hex(i)[2:]` I got the hex value, now by some coding I was able to add the extra zeros and then reverse the code. Now how to write this `'409c0000'` data in the file as hex?
2. The header size is 54 bytes for BMP file, so is there is another way to just store the data in a string like `str='00ffcf4f...'`(upto 54 bytes) and just convert the whole str at once as hex and write it to file?
3. My friend told me to use `unhexlify` from `binascii`,
   by doing `unhexlify('fffcff')` I get `'\xff\xfc\xff'` which is what I want but  when I try `unhexlify('3000')` I get '0\x00'` which is not what I want. It is same for any value containing 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7. Is it the right way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look into using [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) for manipulating and converting bitmaps from within Python. Or you could use the `convert` program from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not writing hex, you are writing binary data. Hexadecimal is a helpful *notation* when dealing with binary data, but don't confuse the notation with the value.

Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to pack integer data into binary structures, the same way C would.

`binascii.unhexlify` also is a good choice, provided you already have the data in a string using hex notation. The output *is correct*, but the binary representation only uses hex escapes for bytes outside the printable ASCII range.

Thus `fffcff` does correctly becomes `\xff\xfc\xff`, representing 3 bytes in hex escape notation, and `3000` is `\x30\x00`, but `\x30` is the `'0'` character in ASCII, so the Python representation for that byte simply uses that ASCII character, as that is the most common way to interpret bytes.

Packing the integer value 40000 using `struct.pack()` as an unsigned integer (little endian) then becomes:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<I', 40000)
'@\x9c\x00\x00'
```

where the `40` byte is represented by the ASCII character for that byte, the `@` glyph.

If this is confusing, you can always create a new hex representation by going the other way and use 0`binascii.hexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to create a hexadecimal representation for yourself, just to debug the output:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<I', 40000))
'409c0000'
```

and you'll see that the `@` byte is still the right hex value.